# How to use "form=form_id" attribute in html5 input

Tags: html

I'm trying to use "form" attribute for html5 input as described here:

[1] http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_input_form.asp

[2] http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_form

The description of the attribute says that form attribute:
"Specifies a space-separated list of id's to one or more forms the  element belongs to"

I'm testing this by using the code below in W3C's TryIt editor (link 2 above)

```
<form action="demo_form.asp" id="form1">
First name: <input type="text" name="fname" /><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<form action="demo_form.asp" id="form2">
First name: <input type="text" name="fname" /><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

Last name: <input type="text" name="lname" form="form1 form2" />
```

I supplied "string_for_form2" in form2 and "lastname" in the lname field. I'm getting the output as:

```
fname=string_for_form2
```

instead of

```
fname=string_for_form2&lname=lastname
```

Any ideas why the result is not as expected ? I've tried on Firefox 17 and Chrome 23.

Thanks

Comment: I know is a question and not an answer, but why you are using two forms?

Comment: I'm trying to make the "lname" field common to n-number of forms. The documentation says form attribute value can be a "space-separated list of id's to one or more forms the element belongs to"

Comment: There are far better resources than w3schools.  For example, MDN (eg https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form )

Answer (score 2):

Because you're trying to assign two form owners.

> "A form-associated element is, by default, associated with its nearest ancestor form element (as described below), but may have a form attribute specified to override this."
>
> > http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#association-of-controls-and-forms

This attribute just allows markup flexibility, it doesn't change the form ownership paradigm from the previous spec.

Comment: Thanks, does this mean there is no way to send "lname" field value along with submission of any of the forms ? PS: I wanted to "Up" but my reputation is too low :)

Comment: Your best bet is to have a hidden field called "lname" in both forms and then have something along the lines of 
`var submit_evt = function(event) {
   event.target.lname.value = visible_lname.value;
    };

    form1.onSubmit = submit_evt;
    form2.onSubmit = submit_evt;`

Answer (score 1):

I could not find anything in the W3C HTML5 specification to support the statement on the [www.w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_form_attributes.asp) site that input element can belong to 2 or more forms.  The input element's owner is always mentioned in singular and never as a list.
Furthermore on [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms_in_HTML) there is explicit statement about the input association with one form only.  The description of the form attribute states:

> form: A string indicating which  element this input is part of.
>   An input can only be in one form.

Answer (score 0):

An input field can only be on one form. It is better to include it within the form scope, for clarity.

Use also *name* instead of only *id* on your forms. Although html5 supports it, what with older browsers? What with IE?

```
<form action="demo_form.asp" name="form1" id="form1">

<form action="demo_form.asp" name="form2" id="form2">
```

Answer (score 0):

use javascript and name form on submit

```
<form action="demo_form.asp" onsubmit= 'this.id="form1"'>
First name: <input type="text" name="fname" /><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<form action="demo_form.asp" onsubmit= 'this.id="form1"'>
First name: <input type="text" name="fname" /><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

Last name: <input type="text" name="lname" form="form1" />
```